# BreezeJS - how do write complex queries?

Tags: typescript, breeze, jaydata

How to write complex queryies with BreezeJS + OData or WebAPI? What I want to be able is something like this in JayData, using Northwind as reference db? My problem is I don't know how to express queries that has both side referencing the database (not a field compared to a constant) and also that has complex logical trees ( a || (b && c))?

```
context.Products.filter(function(product) {
   return (product.Unit_Price < product.Category.BudgetPriceLimit) || 
   (product.Category.IsOnSale && product.Supplier.IsFavored)
}).toArray(...)
```

My other question is about TypeScript + querying. How one can use Arrow functions for queries with BreezeJS? So instead of the expression builders is there a way to say:

```
query(Product => Product.Unit_Price < Product.Category.BudgetPriceLimit)
```

Thank you for your help, sorry if these are obvious questions.

Comment: In a couple of weeks we will release the JayData provider for Breeze. With this provider you'll be able to get best of both worlds: benefit from Breeze Web API server side with JayData providing the client experience with JSLQ and TypeScript support.

Comment: JayData provider for BreezeJS is good why?

Comment: You will be able to extend your Web API code so that it will have metadata. This is what breeze does (among other things) on the server side. After that you can use JayData to express queryies on the way you described also you get TypeScript intellisense support for your entities and queries. Also you can use your local data store with the same API.

Comment: I welcome JayData to the party. I can't tell from this response if JayData offers syntax in their JSLQ for the data value comparisons @BigJ.Lee asks for. Such comparisons are not in the OData spec at this time AFAIK. 

Accepting functions in query clauses is something we've been mulling over. Please [vote for it in User Voice](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3442704-function-parameters-in-query-clauses) if you think it is important.

Comment: I tried that query and it works with a simple API controller if I call directly.

Comment: Hello @Ward :) hello BigJ yes, JSLQ does support this kind of queries as it translates JavaScript bool expressions to OData bool expressions. This latter has full expression tree capabilities. Supporting functions for predicates really makes everyone's life easier, natural syntax, easier way to express simple or complex things. In fact JayData has reusable support for turning functions into model bound expressions, so why not give it a look, you might spare some 4-5 months in coding. Should you be interested I'll be happy to show you in a session.

Comment: Anyway, the Breeze provider for JayData (coming in a couple of weeks) will do much of the work for turning functional predicates to Breeze expression trees.

Comment: As of v 0.84.4, breeze provides full TypeScript support via a 'breeze.d.ts' file available on the breeze website within the breeze zips found [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This post has been edited to correct a mistake on my part as well as new capabilities that have been added to breeze as of v 0. 77.1.***

Good questions!

Breeze now supports cross property query expressions (as of v 0.77.1), such as the following:

```
var shippedLateQuery = EntityQuery.from("Orders")
                                  .where("requiredDate",">","shippedDate");
```

The third parameter ("shippedDate" above) will treated as either a property expression or a literal depending on context.  In general, if the value can be interpreted as a property expression it will be, otherwise it will be treated as a literal.  In most cases this works well, but you can also force the interpretation. Please see the API Docs for more details.

Composing complex queries, i.e. ( a || (b && c)), with breeze is accomplished via Predicates.  There are some good examples here:

[Query Examples - see the Compound Conditions with Predicates topics](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#Where%20clauses%20EntityQuery.where)

Also, the first breeze tutorial here: [Tutorial](http://learn.breezejs.com/) also lets you try out the capabilities (see step 5).

We are actively following Typescript and have plans to fully enable it, but we are still early in the process.

**UPDATE: As of v 0.84.4, Breeze provides full TypeScript support.**

Comment: OData does support those queries refer to http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData%20ABNF.html, search for boolCommonExpr 

in workings example: http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=ProductID%20lt%20SupplierID%20add%205

Comment: I studied the manual on the queries, thanks for the direction.

Comment: sorry for saying this - but it is cumbersome to code 3-4 lines just to have an "and", or at least not intuitive to me. my app will have a huge number of different queries, and my focus is readability.. I have a query that has not less then 20 predicates in it. it would take almost a screen to build it up and a lot of typing...

Comment: plus there are things that simply requires me to have cross property queries - otherwise i have to download way too much data to the client :( but thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem, you understand your issues better than I do. BTW, thanks for the pointer on OData, we will be adding support for cross property predicates later today.

Comment: Thank you very much for the really fast fix. It made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Until Breeze supports field-to-field comparisons, you might consider writing custom query methods on the server-side controller that construct the LINQ queries that can do your field-to-field comparisons. To give your client more flexibility, it can pass parameters that your controller method interprets to influence the query construction; use the *withParameters* clause. You can combine OData query clauses and the *withParameters* clause.

Comment: Do I have to build LINQ queries by hand for this?